# Add a condition before showing details from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a button "**View Contact Details**" in a page. Once it is clicked, it calls "**contact_detail.php**" (code given below).

It first checks:

1. if express interest sent by the logged in user is accepted by the
   user whose contact details are being checked.
2. if yes, it checks how many contacts numbers are viewed by the logged
   in user.

If express interest is not accepted, it errors "This member only shows contact details, if you have already sent him/her express interest, and he/she has accepted it. Please send him/her express interest if you are interested."

If condition 1 is true but if more than 3 contact numbers are already viewed by the logged in user, it errors "You are allowed to view only 3 contacts in a day"

**The file/functions are working perfectly. I just want to add one condition to this**

First and the foremost, check if the user is a paid member. If yes, show the contact number directly without executing condition1. That means, show the following contents along with condition 2

```
<div class="modal-dialog yoyo-large">
.
.
.
<div>
```

If the user is NOT a paid member then run both the conditions 1 and 2 before showing the contact number.

To check if the logged in user is a paid member, it can be checked in the '`register`' table and the field is '`status`' where the value should be '`Paid`' `select * from register where matri_id='$from_id' and status is equal to Paid`.

Can someone help me with the syntax?

Thank you !

```
<?php
require("../connect/report.php");
$mid=$_SESSION['mid'];
$from_id = isset($_REQUEST['toid']) ? $_REQUEST['toid']:0;   
$exp_sel=mysql_query("select * from register where matri_id='$from_id'");
$fet=mysql_fetch_array($exp_sel);                                    
$today=date('Y-m-d');                                                                           
$exp_sel=mysql_query("select * from expressinterest where ei_sender='$mid' and ei_receiver='$from_id' and receiver_response ='Accept'");
$num=mysql_num_rows($exp_sel);
if($num>0)
{
$cnt = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE (pemail = '$mid' or pmatri_id='$mid')";
$cn = mysql_query($cnt);
$ncha = mysql_fetch_array($cn);
if($ncha['p_no_contacts']-$ncha['r_cnt']>0)
{
$ch_viewd=mysql_query("select count(id) as row from today_contact where who='$mid' and on_date='$today'");
$ch_fet=mysql_fetch_array($ch_viewd);
if($ch_fet['row']<3)
{
?>                      
<div class="modal-dialog yoyo-large">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;
      </button>
      <h1 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="color:red;">Remaining Contacts (
        <?php echo ($ncha['p_no_contacts']-$ncha['r_cnt']);?>) 
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="font-size:13px;">         
          <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <tr height="30">
              <td width="80">
                <strong>Matri ID : 
                </strong>
              </td> 
              <td> 
                <?php echo $fet['matri_id']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="30">
              <td>
                <strong>Name : 
                </strong>
              </td> 
              <td> 
                <?php echo $fet['username']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="30">
              <td>
                <strong>Address : 
                </strong> 
              </td> 
              <td> 
                <?php echo $fet['address']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="30">
              <td>
                <strong>Phone : 
                </strong> 
              </td> 
              <td> 
                <?php echo $fet['phone']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="30">
              <td>
                <strong>Mobile : 
                </strong> 
              </td> 
              <td> 
                <?php echo $fet['mobile']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="30">
              <td>
                <strong>Email : 
                </strong>
              </td> 
              <td> 
                <?php echo $fet['email']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>                               
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php       
$chk1=$ncha['r_cnt'];
$inc1=$chk1+1;
$upda="update payments SET r_cnt='$inc1' where  (pemail='$mid' or pmatri_id='$mid')"; 
$up=mysql_query($upda) or die(mysql_error());
$ex=mysql_query("select id from today_contact where who='$mid' and whose='$from_id'");
if(mysql_num_rows($ex)==0)
{                                   
mysql_query("insert into  today_contact (who,whose,on_date) values ('$mid','$from_id',now())");
}
else
{                                       
mysql_query("update  today_contact set on_date=now() where who='$mid' and whose='$from_id'");   
}
?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
}                                           
else
{
?>
<div class="modal-dialog">  
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;
      </button>
      <h1 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="color:red;">Today's limit is over
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;You are allowed to view only 3 contacts in a day
        </h3>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
}
}
else
{
?>
<div class="modal-dialog">  
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;
      </button>
      <h1 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="color:red;">Membership Expired
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;Buy a Premium Membership to contact him right away.
        </h3>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php                                           
}
?>
<?php           
}
else
{
?>
<div class="modal-dialog">  
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;
      </button>
      <h1 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="color:red;">Express interest not accepted
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;This member only shows contact details, if you have already sent him/her express interest,
          <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;and he/she has accepted it.
        </h3>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3 style="color:red;">&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a target="_blank" href="exp_interest.php?ei=<?php echo $from_id; ?>">Please send him/her express interest if you are interested.
          </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: `mysql_` functions? Those are deprecated for a long time now. Why use them? Also: you inject variables in your SQL strings, which represents an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Yes, I came to know about this when i was researching for a solution. However, now entire coding is done that way. I will change this in due course of time. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are asking for the query to check if the user is a paid member?

```
$paidMember = false;
$checkPaidMember = mysql_query("select * from register where matri_id='$from_id' AND status = 'Paid'");
if(mysql_num_rows($checkPaidMember) > 0){
    $paidMember = true;
}
```

Just send the select with the userId and the status needed to the database. If the database returns a dataset there is a user with the id and the status you were asking for.

Trincot is right, you should not use the mysql_* functions and take care of your security vulnerabilities.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php
require("../connect/report.php");
$mid = $_SESSION['mid'];
$from_id = isset($_REQUEST['toid']) ? $_REQUEST['toid'] : 0;
$exp_sel = mysql_query("select * from register where matri_id='$from_id'");
$fet = mysql_fetch_array($exp_sel);
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$exp_sel = mysql_query("select * from expressinterest where ei_sender='$mid' and ei_receiver='$from_id' and receiver_response ='Accept'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($exp_sel);

$paidMember = false;
$checkPaidMember = mysql_query("select * from register where matri_id='$from_id' AND status = 'Paid'");
if(mysql_num_rows($checkPaidMember) > 0){
    $paidMember = true;
}

if ($num > 0 || $paidMember === true) { // added OR in this place for to bypass the first condition if it is a paid member
    $cnt = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE (pemail = '$mid' or pmatri_id='$mid')";
    $cn = mysql_query($cnt);
    $ncha = mysql_fetch_array($cn);
    if ($ncha['p_no_contacts'] - $ncha['r_cnt'] > 0) {
        $ch_viewd = mysql_query("select count(id) as row from today_contact where who='$mid' and on_date='$today'");
        $ch_fet = mysql_fetch_array($ch_viewd);
        if ($ch_fet['row'] < 3 || $paidMember === true) { // added OR in this place to bypass the second condition if it is a paid member
            ?>                      
            <div class="modal-dialog yoyo-large">
                <div class="modal-content">
```

Comment: Yes, I will definitely take care of the mysql vulnerabilities. Regarding my question, i am not actually looking only for the query to check if the user is paid member but i also need to know where I should insert your piece of code within the code i sent. I do not have much of php knowledge but i understood that $paidMember will return true or false depending on the status of the member if paid or not paid but where should i insert it? the objective is to show contact details directly along with the condition2 check if the user is paid, else run both the conditions 1 and 2. Please help Thanx.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I am still trying from my side with no luck! appreciate some help here.

Comment: I think I've got it. To clarify, if the user is a paidMember it always shows the div `<div class="modal-dialog yoyo-large">...</div>`, no matter whether condition 1 or 2 hit or not? Then you can just add an or-clause to your if-constructs.

Comment: I made changes as you suggested. For paid members it shows the contact details (issue is resolved) but unpaid members, it should check for condition1 and show the error `"This member only shows contact details, if you have already sent him/her express interest, and he/she has accepted it. Please send him/her express interest if you are interested."` It is not showing that, instead, it shows `"membership expired, buy a premium membership to contact him right away"` This I think is happening because of the OR operator and it goes ahead and shows error from the `else` statement. Is it? pls help.

Comment: No, it seems the condition1 is fullfilled. But the next condition is not: `if ($ncha['p_no_contacts'] - $ncha['r_cnt'] > 0) {`

Comment: Yes. You are right! When the membership expires or if member is not a paid member, the system deletes the member entry from the `payments` table because of which the select statement on `payments` table do not work and returns zero result. I am thinking of doing away with all the statements and conditions in the code that refers to the `payments` table and shift the `r_cnt` field from `payments` table to `register` table. Do you think it is a good logic and whether it will work?

Comment: I don't know :p What data is in r_cnt?

Comment: Its working now, I just juggled few statements here and there and it worked ! Thanks for your help. Without your help, it would have been difficult for me to get this working. God bless